# C program not running, when changing memory from char to long RISC-V emulator

Tags: c, cygwin, riscv

I am currently creating a RISC-V emulator, where i have created the memory of a char array, this is working. However, the probel rises, as the values that sould be stored in memory are 4bytes, and chars is only 1.
This creates a problem.
So i changed the array to be of longs. When running, this program, the program crashes. A windiw pops up, saying, that it can not edit the file, as it has not been created. After creating it, a Cygwin.S window opens up and the code never runs.
Anyone who has an idea of what to do?

I have attatched images of the current code, whith the char array, whoch works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZhLX.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9PRC.png)

I tried using longs and int and int32_t, nothing is working.

Comment: Please try to identify the problem and post the relevant code here. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How did you verify that a `long` has 4 bytes in your model? I would for the safe side put an assertion into the code to abort early, if this is not the case.

Comment: If `int32_t` does not work either, you have to identify, where exactly things go wrong. You don't provide any error description in your question. However, the loop in your screenshot is a bit strange anyway: Is there a reason why you do write an explicit loop instead of using `memcpy`?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Please don't attach images in this way. You need to insert the code inline so people can see it and answer your question.